# Android using static boolean as flag to determine if activity is visible

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, static-members

I wanted to hear other opinions about using the following method to determine from other activities or services if the activity is visible: the method is about using static `boolean`s as flags, which values depends of activity life-cycle. 
I already implemented this solution and it seems to work alright. However I have doubts whether this is a reliable solution, because, from what i understand, the activity life-cycle is contained inside of an instance of that Activity class, but static methods or fields applies to all instances. For the activity, that visibility status needs to be determined, I've used `singleTask` launch mode, so there shouldn't be more than one instance. 
With that in mind, is it safe to assume that the static boolean will 100% represent the actual status of my activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for sure you can use static boolean flags. However, if you have more options then true/false, I recommend to use `enum` instead.

If your Application has more then 2 Activities, using booleans only leads to hard maintenance.

So for clear code use enum flags like:

```
public enum EActivityState{
  UNKNOWN,
  VISIBLE,
  NOT_VISIBLE,
  LAUNCHED,
  // ....
}
```

After you can use:

```
private EActivityState mActivityState = EActivityState.UNKNOWN;

....

if(EActivityState.LAUNCHED == mActivityState ){
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you said is correct:

> static methods or fields applies to all instances

Check out the Activity Lifecycle here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

and make sure you set your flag correctly, then your solution should be just fine.